# Sort/ Merge arrays using multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, merge

I'm trying to learn multi-threading but cant get the hang of it. I've an example here. 
The idea is to use two threads to sort the two arrays a and b and use another thread to merge the sorted arrays to array c.
This is my code. I tried it with threads didnt work, so i've put up the code without the threads

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int n = r.nextInt(101) + 50;
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      a[i] = r.nextInt(100);
    n = r.nextInt(101) + 50;
    int[] b = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      b[i] = r.nextInt(100);
    SortThread t1 = new SortThread(a);  
    SortThread t2 = new SortThread(b);  
    MergeThread m = new MergeThread(t1.get(),t2.get());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.get()));
  }
}

public class SortThread {
  int[] x; 

  public SortThread(int[] x){
    this.x = x;
    run();    
  }
    public void run(){
      sort(x);
  }

  private void sort(int[] x){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
      int indexOfSmallest = findIndexOfSmallest(x, i);
      int t = x[i];
      x[i] = x[indexOfSmallest];
      x[indexOfSmallest] = t;
    }
  }

  private int findIndexOfSmallest(int[] a, int from){
    int indexOfSmallest = from;

    for(int i = from; i < a.length; i++)
      if(a[i] < a[indexOfSmallest])
        indexOfSmallest = i;
    return indexOfSmallest;
  }


  public int[] get(){
    return x;
  }
}

public class MergeThread {
  int[] a;
  int[] b;
  int[] c;

  public MergeThread(int[] a, int[] b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    c = new int[a.length + b.length];
    run();      
  }
  public void run(){
    merge();
  }

  private void merge(){
    int aIndex = 0, bIndex = 0, cIndex = 0;
    while(aIndex < a.length && bIndex < b.length)
      if(a[aIndex] < b[bIndex])
        c[cIndex++] = a[aIndex++];
      else
        c[cIndex++] = b[bIndex++];

    while(aIndex < a.length)
      c[cIndex++] = a[aIndex++];

    while(bIndex < b.length)
      c[cIndex++] = b[bIndex++];
  }

  public int[] get(){
    return c;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are some answers to this question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114028/merge-sort-using-multi-threading/35115995

Answer (score 0):

A thread should implement the interface runnable and should override the method run.

Please Read Complete reference JAVA, it has many good examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got that part. where I am falling short is not calling the run method explicitly.

Comment: Yes you should initiate the thread. The thread does not inititate itself :)

Comment: like I said I put up my code without the thread part just to show what I am going for. I get the "extends Thread/implements Runnable part." However still not getting the not calling the run method. any suggestions or a link to any examples is highly appreciated

Comment: Like i mentioned even if you extend thread/implement runnable, the thread you are creating has to be started by a start method, which should be overrided again. 

  public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }

After this new can create a new instance of your thread and start it . In your case It should be t1.start and t2.start

Answer (score 0):

Like i mentioned even if you extend thread/implement runnable, the thread you are creating has to be started by a start method, which should be overrided again.

```
 public void start () { System.out.println("Starting " + threadName ); if (t == null) { t = new Thread (this, threadName); t.start (); } }
```

After this new can create a new instance of your thread and start it . In your case It should be

```
  t1.start()
  t2.start()
  m.start()
```